# Get user to input integers

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I want to make a program which keeps prompting the user to input integers(from CUI) until it receives a 'X' or 'x' from the user.
The program then prints out the maximum number, minimum number and average value of the input numbers.

I did manage to get the user to input numbers until someone types 'X', but I can't seem to get it to stop if someone types 'x' and the second bit.

This is the code that I have managed to work out:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number")
while(!in.hasNext("X") && !in.hasNext("x"))
s = in.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("This is the end of the numbers");
```

Any hints on how I proceed further?

Comment: What language are you programming in?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. In java

Comment: At least you should tag the language you are using

Comment: Show the code you have tried please!

Comment: We won't do your homework. Post what you have, and explain your concrete problem.

Comment: Seems like you need a loop, preferrably a while loop to do the trick. while (!userinput.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))

Comment: This is what i have 

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a number");

   while(!in.hasNext("X") && !in.hasNext("x"))

   s = in.next().charAt(0);

   System.out.println("This is the end of the numbers");

Comment: Put your code in your post and format it as code, please.

Comment: sorry, im really new at this. but ive added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do something like this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number")
while(!(in.hasNext("X") || in.hasNext("x")))
    s = in.next().charAt(0);
System.out.println("This is the end of the numbers");
```

Whenever you use  while loop you have to use the {} in case the arguments in the while block are more than 1 line, but if they are just of a line then you can just go on without using the `{}`.

But the problem, you had I suppose is the use of `&&` instead of `||`. What the `&&` (AND) operator does is execute if both the statements are true but a `||` (OR) Operator works if any of the conditions are true.

If you say `while(!in.hasNext("X") && !in.hasNext("x")) it makes no sense as the user input is not both at the same time, but instead if you use` while(!in.hasNext("X") || !in.hasNext("x"))` it makes sense. Understood?

Last of all, about how to calculate the average..., for that what you need to do is store all the input variables into an array and then take out the mean of that or alternatively you could think about it and code something up yourself. Like to take out mean, you could make a variable `sum` and then keep adding the integers the user enters and also keep a variable `count` which will keep the count of the number of integers entered and then at last you could divide both of them to have your answer

**Update:** For checking the minimum and the maximum, what you can do is make 2 new variables like `int min=0, max=0;` and when the user enters a new variable you can check

```
//Note you have to change the "userinput" to the actual user input
if(min>userinput){
    min=userinput;
}
```

and

```
if(max<userinput){
    max=userinput;
}
```

Comment: The || does not seem to work. But the && works fine. For the second bit of the question, finding maximum and minimum numbers; would that come in the while statement? Where would I be storing those values from the user?

Comment: @user3530880 You can store them in an array, but for this you need not store them, just make two more variables `min` and `max` and keep the least and the highest int in that, and everytime the user enters a new variable check if it is less than min, store that into `min` and check if it > than max store that in max and so on... Got it? If yes you can upvote my answer and also put a tick besides it if it satisfies your needs

Comment: The `||` is wrong. See De Morgan's laws: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws. You can write is as `!in.hasNext("X") && !in.hasNext("x") == !(in.hasNext("X") || in.hasNext("x"))`.

Comment: Im really new to programming, I wouldnt know how to keep the lowest number in min and highest in max and keep checking. Ill try something out though.

Comment: No you are taking the opposite way.

Comment: @feuerball What do you mean? The brackets? You just said we can write it as `!(in.hasNext("X") || in.hasNext("x"))`

Comment: Yes I mean the brackets. At the moment it's `!a && !b`. This is the same as `!(a || b)`. You suggested to write `!a || !b`, which is the same as `!(a && b)`. This evaluates only to `false` if both inputs at the same time are `X` **and** `x`. But this is not possible and you stay in the loop.

Comment: @feuerball I think this is correct `while((!in.hasNext("X")) || (!in.hasNext("x")))
` right?

Comment: If you enter `X`, `in.hasNext("X")` evaluates to `true`. Thus `!in.hasNext("X")` evaluates to false. Since you entered `X`, `in.hasNext("x")` will evaluate to `false` and `!in.hasNext("x")` to `true`. Well, `false || true` evaluates to `true`. But in this case your expression should evaluate to `false`, because an `X` has been entered.

Comment: @feuerball Oops! I get it, I am so sorry I know that I will just update my answer

Comment: @feuerball I think that it is correct now. could you just cross check it anyway?

Comment: Yeah now it's correct, but the expression has the exact same meaning as the expression of the op, due to De Morgan's law. There was nothing wrong with the original code.

Answer (score 0):

This would fit your needs:

```
public void readNumbers() {
    // The list of numbers that we read
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    // The scanner for the systems standard input stream
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // As long as there a tokens...
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {  // ...check if the next token is an integer
            // Get the token converted to an integer and store it in the list
            numbers.add(scanner.nextInt());
        } else if (scanner.hasNext("X") || scanner.hasNext("x")) {  // ...check if 'X' or 'x' has been entered
            break;  // Leave the loop
        }
    }

    // Close the scanner to avoid resource leaks
    scanner.close();

    // If the list has no elements we can return
    if (numbers.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No numbers were entered.");
        return;
    }

    // The following is only executed if the list is not empty/
    // Sort the list ascending
    Collections.sort(numbers);

    // Calculate the average
    double average = 0;

    for (int num : numbers) {
        average += num;
    }

    average /= numbers.size();

    // Print the first number
    System.out.println("Minimum number: " + numbers.get(0));
    // Print the last number
    System.out.println("Maximum number: " + numbers.get(numbers.size() - 1));
    // Print the average
    System.out.println("Average:        " + average);
}
```

Comment: Just adding all of the code is not a good practice I think, No offence but the guy is new. You can tell him how to do what to read and give him some parts of code but you shouldn't just give him all of the code. You should sort of tell him how to code but should not code it all up for him

Comment: @feuerball thank you for the answer, but I did not understand half of it. So I might just keep giving it a go and try to understand it. Ill surely revert back if I have an issue understanding stuff.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: @feuerball thanks for the comments in the code. Its easier to understand now. :)